# Работает ли (если да, как) pathPattern с scheme content

Tags: android, intent-filter, pathpattern

Если делаю intent-filter по pathPattern со схемами file или http, всё работает. Но вот такое:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

<data
    android:host="*"
    android:pathPattern=".*\\.tar"
    android:scheme="content"></data> 
</intent-filter>
```

не обрабатывается. Вариант с mime-type не вариант (во-первых, хочу использовать своё расширение файла, а во-вторых, (телефон виноват?) tar-архивы обычно отдаются как text/plain, что совсем неудобно). Собственно, вопрос, как сделать, чтобы файлы (ладно, uri) из разных приложений (т.е. именно content:/) могли открывать в соответствии с их расширением?

Answer (score 0):

`Uri` не обязан содержать имя файла: приложение, которое его расшаривает, имеет полное право вписать в `uri` что в голову взбредёт разработчику.
Застарелый геморрой - этот убогий `pathPattern`.
Во-первых, он чувствителен к регистру, то есть для `tar`, `TAR`, `TaR`, `taR`, etc. нужен отдельный паттерн.
Во-вторых: он отваливается на первом вхождении первого символа, если следом за ним нет второго. Если весь путь содержит более одной точки нужно добавлять паттерн на каждое возможное их количество, типа такого:

```
     <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
         android:pathPattern=".*\\.tar" />
     <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
         android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.tar" />
     <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
         android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..tar" />
     <data android:scheme="http" android:host="*"
         android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.tar" />
```

Плюс все варианты регистра = "скажем дружно ..." и вместо полезных инструментов пойдём писать очередную ктопко-тыкалку с рекламой, чтобы Гугл получал прибыль с её показов - а от ковыряния юзеров в локальных файлах какой выхлоп!?...

Comment: Насчёт всех вариантов регистра неактуально. Я хочу использовать своё расширение, регистр которого знаю. Фактически это tar, но мне нужно, чтобы система открывала файлы с определённым расширением в определённом приложении. На компьютере это решается проще, можно поправить /etc/magic (ибо и содержимое файла известно), но, как я понимаю, в Андроиде это невозможно. И опять же, проблема только со схемой content:/

Comment: То что вы знаете не мешает юзеру где-то взять/сохранить/переименовать файл с неправильным регистром и пытаться его открыть. К сожалению да, в Андроиде невозможно со 100% гарантией подписаться на расширение файла и даже mime-type. А тем более зарегистрировать в системе кастомный тип. И странно что гугла не задолбали этим вопросом за всё время существования ОС.

Comment: Скорее, предполагалось так: чтобы программа сделала определённое действие (условно, получила доп. данные, которые передаются только офлайн), я ему (юзеру) даю tar файл ( или даже просто пишу, как создать его), он переименовывает его по определённому шаблону и должно работать. Так вот, это работает при открытии из файл менеджеров (и то не из всех). Но если далее этот файл передаётся через (например) телеграм, то при открытии напрямую из тг, у него (файла) расширение остаётся верным, а вот mime становится text/plain. Отсюда и вопрос. (Пока настроил фильтр на text/plain, но это ж ерунда...)

Comment: В том же тг, оказывается, Один и тот же принятый файл может иметь разные типы пр получении разными способами. В общем, похоже, ставить обработчик имеет смысл на \*/\*, что явно не comme il faut, но это уже какие-то системные ограничения

Comment: Ограничения... - да просто болт забили и теперь нет никаких общих правил по оформлению таких интентов и фильтров, каждый выкручивается как может. Поэтому адекватные приложения делают несколько попыток сформировать интент, а если уже никто не отвечает посылают тупо `"*/*"` и это было хоть как-то работоспособно с тем же `pathPattern` - но нате вам запрет на схему `file://`, чтоб служба мёдом не казалась. В общем всё что можно сделать - подогнать набор фильтров под несколько популярных приложений, отдать в бета-тест и допиливать уже по результатам. Потом оперативно допиливать по жалобам юзеров.